# Trouble installing PHP/Mongo driver with rpm file

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm installing PHP 7.3 with MongoDB driver 1.8.2 on a RHEL 7 server with limited internet access (yes, we are woefully out of date). So I have a downloaded rpm: `sclo-php73-php-pecl-mongodb-1.8.2-1.el7.x86_64.rpm`. Problem is I don't know what to do from there. I ran:

`yum -ih install sclo-php73-php-pecl-mongodb-1.8.2-1.el7.x86_64.rpm`

And it's already installed, but I don't see where the driver is (mongo.so) doing a find command. Is there more setup I need to do? I've seen documentation about using Composer, but I don't seem to have that file either. I'm a software person, not server at all, so I really don't know what I'm doing...

ETA: I also tried using pecl, searching for both mongo and mongodb, and the result is not found.

`No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/mongodb" install failed`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [centos packages site](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-sclo-aarch64/sclo-php73-php-pecl-mongodb-1.8.2-1.el7.aarch64.rpm.html) lists the following files in that rpm:

```
/etc/opt/rh/rh-php73/php.d/50-mongodb.ini
/opt/rh/rh-php73/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/mongodb.so
/opt/rh/rh-php73/root/usr/share/doc/pecl/mongodb/CONTRIBUTING.md
/opt/rh/rh-php73/root/usr/share/doc/pecl/mongodb/CREDITS
/opt/rh/rh-php73/root/usr/share/doc/pecl/mongodb/README.md
/opt/rh/rh-php73/root/usr/share/doc/pecl/mongodb/THIRD_PARTY_NOTICES
/opt/rh/rh-php73/root/usr/share/licenses/sclo-php73-php-pecl-mongodb-1.8.2/LICENSE
/opt/rh/rh-php73/root/var/lib/pear/pkgxml/sclo-php73-php-pecl-mongodb.xml
```

The installer should have created the directory /opt/rh/rh-php73/root/usr/lib64/php/modules with mongodb.so in it.